# Card hover push to top effect

Tags: css, reactjs

Hi I'm trying to push the top in my texts
and I used the opacity: 0
and when it's hovering I use a padding-bottom
but I have a problem with this when the height of this hidden text is high as it will continue to occupy this space because it is not with the display none
I'm not able to solve this:

[image]

but I need my text to be at the end of the div like this:

[image]

And it doesn't start at the end of my div because even with opacity 0 my text is still there

code:

```
 <TestingLive isHover={hoveredCards.card1}>
        <div
          className="a"
          onMouseOver={() => updateHoveredCards("card1", true)}
          onMouseOut={() => updateHoveredCards("card1", false)}
        >
          <div className="content-header">
            <p className="text-title">testing</p>
            <h3 className="content-text" style={{ color: "#fff" }}>
              testing
            </h3>
            <p className="date-text" style={{ color: "#fff" }}>
              <span>a</span>
              10 de dezembro de 2020
            </p>
            <p className="content-spoiler">
              show this text bottom on hover show this text bottom on hover show
              this text bottom on hover show this text bottom on hover
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </TestingLive>
```

css:

```
const TestingLive = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "a b c"
    "a d e";
  grid-gap: 4px;
  grid-template-columns: 40vw 1fr 1fr;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 60vh;
  min-height: 60vh;
  padding: 0 20px;}
  & > div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -200px -200px 5px 500px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset -200px -200px 5px 500px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
    box-shadow: inset -200px -200px 5px 500px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-image: url("https://www.cronosolucoes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/futuristic-technology-background-hd-overlay-115379004773cf6twdsmd.png");
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  & .a {
    grid-area: a;
  }
  & .content-header {
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    ${({ isHover }) =>
      isHover &&
      `
    `}
  }
  & .content-spoiler {
    max-width: 300px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    opacity: 0;
    color: white;
    display:none;
    ${({ isHover }) =>
      isHover &&
      `
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    opacity:1;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    `}
    margin-top:10px;
  }
  & .text-title {
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    line-height: 13px;
    pointer-events: auto;
    background-position: top center;
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #009ffd, #2a2a72);
    animation: ${HeaderKeyFrame} 5s ease infinite;
    background-size: 150% 100%;
    color: #fff;
  }
  & .content-text {
    max-width: 300px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 1.07692308rem !important;
    font-family: Roboto Slab, serif;
    font-weight: 400;
  }
  & .date-text {
    max-width: 250px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 0.6692308rem !important;
    font-family: sans-serif, serif;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    font-weight: 400;
    & > span {
      margin-right: 5px;
    }
  }
`;
```

example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/great-snowflake-4dwpy

Comment: You have a couple of options here. You could `flex-shrink` to make that items super small. Or a simpler solution is to animate the `max-height` from `0` to a value you know will always be greater than what the content will be (like `100vw`) but don't overdo it (see [Using CSS Transitions on Auto Dimensions](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/#article-header-id-1) in the first technique's downsides section)

Comment: Can you help me?
I tried with the height but using the height the animation is something strange

Comment: You need to use display:none and display:block on hover